# How to select an element which is made after page-loading using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```js
$("body").on('click', '#btn', function(e) {
    $('div').after('<span>it is a test</span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
<button  id="btn">click</button>
```

Now I want to set a CSS property (for e.g `color: red;`) to that `<span>` using `.css()`. How should I select it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your page is simple you can select your span just by using `tagName` selector and jquery `next()` function, e.g :

```
$("div").next('span').css("color", "red");
```

If you will add other elements better if you can use `id` or `class` to identify your tags, e.g using `class` :

```
$('div').after('<span class="span1">it is a test</span>'); //Definition
$("div").next('.span1').css("color", "red"); //Selection
```

---

**Snippet :**

```js
$("body").on('click', '#btn', function(e) {
  $('div').after('<span>it is a test</span>');
  $("div").next('span').css("color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Div</div><br>
<button  id="btn">click</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: May you please give me a fiddle?

Comment: `$('div').after('<span>it is a test</span>').next('span').css('color', 'red');`

Comment: Thanks @Shikkediel for your intervention, feel free to add any suggestion in question.

Comment: Cheers, I'll leave your answer be though... it just a small optimisation versus readability.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, Your span has **ID** named **spnText**

then, you can add **css** in the following way

```
$("span#spnText").css("attributeName", "attributeValue");
```

Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/c8vLm9w8/